# how to implement interface through reflection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, interface

My Code is like
`Assembly assemblyX = Assembly.Load("xyz.abc.DataObjects");
Type t = assemblyX.GetType("xyz.abc.DataObjects." + ValueStr);`

Everything is good till this point. Now i want to implement interface on 't' which is 'xDataObject' and require a generic i.e "CurrentDataObject" in < > operators like `xDataObject<CurrentDataObject>`. This interface consists many member functions, which I want to use in reflection. According to my research on it, the problem is in this next line, which works fine until we don't need interface i.e 
`Object objClass = (Object)Activator.CreateInstance(t);`
Help me. I'm new to Generics. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot create an instance of an interface but of a class implementing that interface.

Comment: good point, i've to try this. thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at *Castle DynamicProxy*. It lets you create proxies of your types on run-time which implement interfaces, base classes and many other things.

Check its documentation [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md).

Comment: i don't wanna do this on runtime bro.
i wanna access all member functions on that instance, i mean, it will probably showing all member functions through intellisense after implementing Interface on it (Instance).

Comment: Reflection means runtime, seems you need to explain better what you want to do and when.

Comment: @emles I would avoid the "bro" thing. While it's during run-time, you're creating new types as if they would be created during compile-time using Reflection Emit under the hoods. See for example this other Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651455/using-reflection-emit-to-create-a-class-implementing-an-interface. Instead of using this lower-level API, Castle DynamicProxy makes it easier.

Comment: @emles Recently I used DynamicProxy to implement this project from the scratch: http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog Maybe you can take a look at my code to get ideas..

Comment: yeah, i know
anyways, the only problem is that generic between angle brackets in interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native solution for what you want as generic checking is made at compile time. At runtime you must use `dynamic` in your code or the previously recommended dll.